# How to prove that the principal minor criterion of Hurwitz does not always imply positive semi definiteness if principal minors are $\geq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multilinear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

> Let $ n\ge2$ and $A:=((a_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq k})  \in \mathrm{Mat}(n\times n,\mathbb{R} )$ a symmetric matrix with the property that all principal minors are $\geq 0$ or in other words:
> $\det((a_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq k}) \geq 0$ for $k=1,...,n$.
>
> Does it always follow that $A$ is positive semi definite or is there for $n\geq 2$ a matrix $A$ with $ x^{t}Ax<0$ for a $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Which one are you talking about? [Hurwitz's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_matrix) or [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion)? Hurwitz's criterion is about the leading principal minors of the **Hurwitz matrix** of $A$ rather than the principal minors of $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $A=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \\ \end{array} } \right]$
which meets the criteria. Now put $x=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc} 0 \\ 1 \\ \end{array} } \right]$ and $x^T Ax=-1$.